# Spark Dataframe GroupBy and compute Complex aggregate function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark dataframe , I need to compute the percentage by using the below 
complex formula :

Group by "KEY " and calculate "re_pct" as  ( sum(sa) / sum( sa / (pct/100)  ) ) * 100

For Instance , Input Dataframe is

```
val values1 = List(List("01", "20000", "45.30"), List("01", "30000", "45.30"))
  .map(row => (row(0), row(1), row(2)))

val DS1 = values1.toDF("KEY", "SA", "PCT")
DS1.show()

+---+-----+-----+
|KEY|   SA|  PCT|
+---+-----+-----+
| 01|20000|45.30|
| 01|30000|45.30|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Expected Result :

```
+---+-----+--------------+
|KEY|    re_pcnt         |
+---+-----+--------------+
| 01|   45.30000038505   |
+---+-----+--------------+
```

I have tried to calculate as below

```
    val result = DS1.groupBy("KEY").agg(((sum("SA").divide(
  sum(
    ("SA").divide(
      ("PCT").divide(100)
    )
  )
)) * 100).as("re_pcnt"))
```

But facing Error:(36, 16) value divide is not a member of String ("SA").divide({

Any suggestion on implementing the above logic ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try importing `spark.implicits._` and then use `$` to refer to a column.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

val result = DS1.groupBy("KEY")
  .agg(((sum($"SA").divide(sum(($"SA").divide(($"PCT").divide(100))))) * 100)
  .as("re_pcnt"))
```

Which will give you the requested output.

If you do not want to import you can always use the `col()` command instead of `$`.

---

It is possible to use a string as input to the `agg()` function with the use of `expr()`. However, the input string need to be changed a bit. The following gives exactly the same result as before, but uses a string instead:

```
val opr = "sum(SA)/(sum(SA/(PCT/100))) * 100"
val df = DS1.groupBy("KEY").agg(expr(opr).as("re_pcnt"))
```

Note that `.as("re_pcnt")` need to be inside the `agg()` method, it can not be outside.

Comment: So in this case are for of the sum() performed with a groupy key or only the last one

Comment: @Dee: Not sure if I understand you question correctly or not, but the aggregation is performed separably on each key. If there are multiple keys in the input then the output will have multiple rows.

Comment: Apologies my question was very badly written. I've played around with this and realised what I want to do isn't possible i.e. what I'd like to do is sum( log(price) * (quantity / sum(quantity)) ) or sum( log(price) * (quantity / sum(quantity) over (partition by id_col) )) but I can't use nest an agg or window function with an aggregate func. In this case the outer sum()

Answer (score 0):

Your code works almost perfectly. You just have to put the '$' symbol in order to specify you're passing a column:

```
val result = DS1.groupBy($"KEY").agg(((sum($"SA").divide(
  sum(
    ($"SA").divide(
      ($"PCT").divide(100)
    )
  )
)) * 100).as("re_pcnt"))
```

Here's the output:

```
result.show()
+---+-------+                                                                   
|KEY|re_pcnt|
+---+-------+
| 01|   45.3|
+---+-------+
```